# On raspberry pi terminal cv2 works but on my project didnt work how can i fix this

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, opencv

I tried on python3 terminal ;

```
    pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python3
    Python 3.7.3 (default, Dec 20 2019, 18:57:59) 
    [GCC 8.3.0] on linux
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> import cv2
    >>>
```

It seems nothing wrong
But i want to run my py file

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo python /home/pi/berber/ornek.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/berber/ornek.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
ImportError: No module named cv2
```

Terminal says you dont have cv2.
But if i dont have cv2 python3 command cant import cv2.
How can i fix this problem

Comment: Try `sudo python3 /home/pi/berber/ornek.py`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first example demonstrates that your normal (non-root) user's Python3 environment has OpenCV installed.

Your second example demonstrates that OpenCV is not installed in the root user's Python environment.

So, you are confusing two different users and potentially two different Python versions. You can work out what you are running when a normal user with:

```
type python3
```

Then, unless you have installed OpenCV privately for that user, you should be able to run the same thing under `sudo`.